# `@Autowire` is working,Even though No Annotation replacement for <context:annotation-config />,

Tags: java, spring

I had a project which was developed using config xml file,we have to changed it Annotation based configuration-

```
    <!--To Scan stereo type bean such as (@Component,@Controller,etc)-->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ttnd.springdemo.*" />

    <!--To Activete web related annotaion such as (@RequestMapping,@ModelAttribute etc)-->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!--To Register All Bean Post Processor which activate respective annotaion those are registered in container by @ComponentScan such as AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor for @Autowire -->
    <context:annotation-config />
```

I replaced following xml element by respective Annotation-

`<context:component-scan>` by `@ComponantScan`

`<mvc:annotation-driven />` by `@EnableWebMvc`

But didn't use any replacement for `<context:annotation-config />`,Even though `@Autowire` is working!

From where `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` coming now!

Below is my Configuration class-

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.ttnd.mvc_mod.controller","com.ttnd.mvc_mod.services"})
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig  {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

Comment: When using java based configuration it is assumed that you use annotations hence no explicit enabling is needed.

Comment: @M.Deinum So `@AnnotationDrivenConfig` is not exact replacement for `<context:annotation-config />` ?

Comment: You don't need it as that is already implied also that annotation isn't even part of standard Spring (but probably of the old Spring Java Config project which was a sandbox for the current support).

Comment: means `@AnnotationDrivenConfig` is  replacement for` <context:annotation-config />` but registering BeanPostprocessor is automatically enabled even thoug thereis no `@AnnotationDrivenConfig`.my understanding is correct?

Comment: That annotation is part of an old and abandoned project (for years already). There is no replacement because you don't need a replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be what you are looking for [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch06s02.html)

```
@Configuration
@AnnotationDrivenConfig
public class Config {
    // may now use @Autowired to reference beans from other @Configuration classes, XML, etc
}
```